# Spark: Use same OneHotEncoder on multiple dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have two `DataFrames` with the same columns and I want to convert
a categorical column into a vector using One-Hot-Encoding. The problem is
that for example, in the training set 3 unique values may occur while in
the test set you may have less than that.

```
Training Set:        Test Set:

+------------+       +------------+
|    Type    |       |    Type    |
+------------+       +------------+
|     0      |       |     0      | 
|     1      |       |     1      | 
|     1      |       |     1      | 
|     3      |       |     1      | 
+------------+       +------------+
```

In this case the `OneHotEncoder` creates vectors with different length on the training and test set (since each element of the vector represents the presence of a unique value).

Is it possible to use the same `OneHotEncoder` on multiple `DataFrames`?
There is no `fit` function and so I don't know how I could do that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.0**:

Old-style `OneHotEncoder` has been removed and `OneHotEncoderEstimator` has been renamed to `OneHotEncoder`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, OneHotEncoderModel

encoder = (OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCols(["type"])
    .setOutputCols(["encoded"])
    .setDropLast(False))
```

**Spark >= 2.3**:

Spark 2.3 add new `OneHotEncoderEstimator` and `OneHotEncoderModel` classes which work as you expect them to work here.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator, OneHotEncoderModel

encoder = (OneHotEncoderEstimator()
    .setInputCols(["type"])
    .setOutputCols(["encoded"])
    .setDropLast(False))
model = encoder.fit(training)  # type: OneHotEncoderModel

model.transform(training).show()
# +----+-------------+
# |type|      encoded|
# +----+-------------+
# | 0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
# | 1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
# | 1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
# | 3.0|(4,[3],[1.0])|
# +----+-------------+

model.transform(testing).show()
# +----+-------------+
# |type|      encoded|
# +----+-------------+
# | 0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
# | 1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
# | 1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
# | 1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
# +----+-------------+
```

**Spark < 2.3**

`OneHotEncoder` is not intended to be used alone. Instead it should be a part of a `Pipeline` where it can leverage column metadata. Consider following example:

```
training = sc.parallelize([(0., ), (1., ), (1., ), (3., )]).toDF(["type"])
testing  = sc.parallelize([(0., ), (1., ), (1., ), (1., )]).toDF(["type"])
```

When you use encoder directly it has no knowledge about the context:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder().setOutputCol("encoded").setDropLast(False)


encoder.setInputCol("type").transform(training).show()
## +----+-------------+
## |type|      encoded|
## +----+-------------+
## | 0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
## | 3.0|(4,[3],[1.0])|
## +----+-------------+


encoder.setInputCol("type").transform(testing).show()
## +----+-------------+
## |type|      encoded|
## +----+-------------+
## | 0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
## +----+-------------+
```

Now lets add required metadata. It can be for example by using `StringIndexer`:

```
indexer = (StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("type")
  .setOutputCol("type_idx")
  .fit(training))
```

If you apply encoder on the indexed column you'll get consistent encoding on both data sets:

```
(encoder.setInputCol("type_idx")
   .transform(indexer.transform(training))
   .show())

## +----+--------+-------------+
## |type|type_idx|      encoded|
## +----+--------+-------------+
## | 0.0|     1.0|(3,[1],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|     0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|     0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
## | 3.0|     2.0|(3,[2],[1.0])|
## +----+--------+-------------+
```

(encoder
       .setInputCol("type_idx")
       .transform(indexer.transform(testing))
       .show())

```
## +----+--------+-------------+
## |type|type_idx|      encoded|
## +----+--------+-------------+
## | 0.0|     1.0|(3,[1],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|     0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|     0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
## | 1.0|     0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
## +----+--------+-------------+
```

Please note that the labels you get this way don't reflect values in the input data. If consistent encoding is a hard requirement you should provide schema manually:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType

meta = {"ml_attr": {
    "name": "type",
    "type": "nominal", 
    "vals": ["0.0", "1.0", "3.0"]
}}

schema = StructType([StructField("type", DoubleType(), False, meta)])

training = sc.parallelize([(0., ), (1., ), (1., ), (3., )]).toDF(schema)
testing  = sc.parallelize([(0., ), (1., ), (1., ), (1., )]).toDF(schema)

assert (
    encoder.setInputCol("type").transform(training).first()[-1].size == 
    encoder.setInputCol("type").transform(testing).first()[-1].size
)
```

Answer (score -1):

We can extend this to multiple columnar dataset by creating a meta matrix and creating multiple OneHotEncoders.
These steps can be staged in the pipeline.